# OpenTok learning-open-tok issue

Tags: php, android, opentok

I've been following the steps at this link: https://github.com/opentok/learning-opentok-php, and I can't get past the first step because I don't understand what I have to do on this part:

> The run-demo file starts the PHP CLI development server (requires PHP >= 5.4) on port 8080. If you want to run your server on another port, edit the file. Finally, start the server using the run-demo script.

And then when i actually run the run-demo script and follow the link: http://localhost:8080/session i get this message on screen "You must run `composer install` in the sample app directory", and if i try to run the composer it doesent run.

Comment: In the README you're mentioning, on the line after the part you're quoting, it says `./run-demo`. Just enter that into a shell and your server should be running. Don't forget to follow the steps before this one, they're probably important.

Comment: if i run the command into the shell it says that "." is not a recognized internal command

Comment: Edit your question to include more info - what OS you're using, what exactly you've tried and what the output is.

Comment: no its ok i fixed it thanks